# Cannot use package "ks.test", "chisq.test", "wilcox.test" in R 3.1.0, 3.0.3 or 2.14.1 on Mac OSX 10.9.2

Tags: r, macos, unit-testing

test", "chisq.test" and "wilcox.test" packages for homework calculations when using R 3.0.3 on OSX 10.9.2. It worked fine.

After upgrading R to 3.1.0 I tried to download the package "ks.test" again using install.packages("ks.test"). However it returned "package ‘ks.test’ is not available (for R version 3.1.0)". Same was "chisq.test" and "wilcox.test".

I tried to downgrade my R version to 3.0.3 and 2.14.1. The same results returned, e.g. "package ‘ks.test’ is not available (for R version 2.14.1)".

Other packages like "survival" and "MASS" were not affected.

I would like to know the reason. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ks.test`, `chisq.test`, and `wilcox.test` are functions in the stats package.  They aren't packages.  You can just use these functions directly without downloading any additional packages.